# Resolving controllers inside component in MVC3 with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

I have a component which is able to to check it controller's action is accessible for currently logged user.

```
public class ControllerAccessChecker : IControllerAccessChecker
{
    ILifetimeScope _scope;

    public ControllerAccessChecker(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        _scope = scope;
    }

    public bool IsAccessible<TController>(Expression<Action<TController>> action, RequestContext requestContext) where TController : Controller
    {
        var actionName = GetActionName(action);
        var result = false;

        using (var childScope = _scope.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var controller = childScope.Resolve<TController>(); 
            result = HasActionPermission(requestContext, actionName, controller);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static string GetActionName(LambdaExpression actionExpression)
    {
        object operand;
        if (actionExpression.Body as UnaryExpression != null)
        {
            operand = ((UnaryExpression)actionExpression.Body).Operand;
        }
        else
        {
            operand = actionExpression.Body;
        }
        MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)operand;
        return methodCallExpression.Method.Name;
    }

    private static bool HasActionPermission(RequestContext requestContext, string actionName, ControllerBase controller)
    {
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, controller);

        var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controller.GetType());

        var actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(controllerContext, actionName);

        return ActionIsAuthorized(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
    }


    private static bool ActionIsAuthorized(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        if (actionDescriptor == null)
            return false;

        AuthorizationContext authContext = new AuthorizationContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);

        foreach (Filter authFilter in FilterProviders.Providers.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor).Where(x => x.Instance is IAuthorizationFilter))
        {
            ((IAuthorizationFilter)authFilter.Instance).OnAuthorization(authContext);

            if (authContext.Result != null)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see I am injecting `ILifetimeScope` into constructor and I am not sure if this is good practice. Also I am not sure if I am doing right thigs inside `IsAccessible` method. This Autofac's scope hierarchy approach is really confusing for me.

I was thinking about some sort of abstract factory for controllers but it seems to be not easy to implement with Autofac. I found some articles and answers here about using `IIndex<,>` and registration with `.Keyed()` but I don't think this is really what should be use in case like this. I mean I know what type I need so it should be easy just to ask for it.

Comment: Why are doing that programmatically instead of using the [Authorize] attribute?

Comment: Authorize attributes are there and this little thing can analyze all these authorzation filters (which can be registered on action, controller, globally or via IoC container). So it can tell you if current user has access to any other action or not. I think similar approach is used somewhere in MvcContrib for generating menu or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than injecting the lifetime scope, you can use `AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope` - Unless you're using this outside a web context, I'd probably go with that.

One thing on the design of this: in `IsAccessible` you're resolving the actual controller, which also means you're resolving and instantiating all of its dependencies, all the way down the chain. If you're doing this in a menu system or somewhere that you're doing a lot of these on every request, that's a lot of controllers (and controller dependencies). And if your controller dependencies are, say, database connections or WCF service proxies... well, that could get pretty expensive just to check accessibility. Something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your notes. I cannot found other way how to get all filters without instantiating controller because I must create `ControlerContext`. But all expensive dependencies in controllers should be lazy, therefore they will be created only when they will be used for the first time. Also dependencies will be never created when requested action is not using them but other action still need them.